# How to parse multiple items from DynamoDB in JSON format using PHP?

Tags: python, php, json, amazon-web-services

I'm using PHP & cURL to make an API call that returns all items for a given primary key(e.g. userId), which include string data for a job application such as "Company":"Apple", "JobLocation":"New York", etc...

The AWS Lambda function which the API calls simply uses the AWS SDK and returns the items in a format as below.

```
[{"Location": "San Diego", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "NASA", "Progress": "draft"}, {"Location": "Irvine", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "Google", "Progress": "submitted"}, {"Location": "Hawthorne", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "SpaceX", "Progress": "interviewed"}]
```

If I use `json_decode($data, true)` all I get is an array of length 1 that contains the entire string.
I also tried doing `substr($data, 1, -1)` to get rid of the open and close brackets, then did `$newData = json_encode($data)` and once again `$userData = json_decode($newData, true)` but it returns an array of length 1 and I cannot reference any of the values based on key, for example `$company = $userData['Company']`. My goal is to display certain application data in a summary view such as Company, Title, Location, and Progress.

Does the Lambda function need to have a key for each application, in order for it to work properly with `json_decode($data)`? As in

```
{"application": [{"Location": "San Diego", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "NASA", "Progress": "draft"}, {"Location": "Irvine", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "Google", "Progress": "submitted"}, {"Location": "Hawthorne", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "SpaceX", "Progress": "interviewed"}]}
```

Looking for any advice on whether this is possible with PHP or if I need to explore other options. Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like its being double encoded, decode it again or fix the response.. https://3v4l.org/KEYgG

Comment: Thanks for your input. It turned out that decoding the json twice was necessary, I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I usually using PHP for manage the Json or Array.

You can try my example script, like this:

```
<?php
$data = '[{"Location": "San Diego", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "NASA", "Progress": "draft"}, {"Location": "Irvine", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "Google", "Progress": "submitted"}, {"Location": "Hawthorne", "Title": "Developer", "Company": "SpaceX", "Progress": "interviewed"}]';

$jsonToArray = json_decode($data, true);
//print_r($jsonToArray); //if you try this code you will see that $jsonToArray is array now, not string.

?>

<!--to make this array into data as row or table, you can use foreach to display all data -->
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>Progress</td>
  </tr>
  
  <?php foreach ($jsonToArray as $key=>$value) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $value['Location'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['Title'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['Company'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['Progress'];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me with the foreach once I got the json decoded properly.